# Curl error as Bad Request

Tags: curl, windows-10, bodylabs

I'm new to Android and Visual Studio.I am working on a project implementing body labs blue API.I got access key and secret key and using CURL for API call as per the documentation I'm facing problem with passing the https request using Curl in command prompt.
On executing the Curl on windows 10 with Access and Secret Keys,it shows bad request exception.
This is the URL I passed in Curl
   https://blue-api.bodylabs.com/account-settings/
from the documentation.I am even providing an image of the Cmd hope it helps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d74yg.png)

Answer (score 0):

The **Bad Request** you got is not a curl error, it an HTTP Error 400. Meaning the Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) was 'malformed' i.e. did not respect the HTTP protocol completely. So the Web server was unable to understand the request and process it. You may want to checkout [How to Fix a 400 Bad Request Error](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-a-400-bad-request-error-2617988)